# VLAN routing query on HP Switch

Tags: networking, routing, hp, switch, vlan

I have Layer 3 HP switches throughout my organisation. They are set up to perform routing between all the VLANs connected to them, and everything is working.

I am pretty proficient with using them, but this is a weird one.

I want to route between some VLANs and not others. So, (and I am giving an abstract version of the issue here) If I have VLANs 10, 11, 12 and 13, I want to route between 10 and 11 and I want to route between 12 and 13 but not between 10 / 11 and 12 / 13.

Something like this:

```
10<==>11 || 12<==>13
```

Normally I would just set no ip address for a VLAN I don't want to route, but the problem is I want all VLANS to be capable of routing, just not to all other VLANs.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Which HP ProCurve switch model(s) do you have in your organization?

Comment: did you say that you have routing enabled on all your switches and all your switches are doing routing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use ACLs.

Also make sure "ip routing" is enabled in your config.

See the [HP Advanced Traffic Management Guide](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c02609963-3.pdf).

Can you share the model(s) of the switches involved?

```
ip access-list extended "SecureVLAN20-30"
    10 permit ip 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255
    20 permit ip 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255
```